# Dynamic SQL | PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I've run into trouble with Dynamic SQL, I want to be able to display the department_id:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pro_two_tables
    (p_input VARCHAR2) IS
     v_department_id employees.department_id%TYPE;

BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
       'SELECT department_id
    /* MYSTERY FOR ME */
           FROM ' || p_input || '
              WHERE manager_id = 205';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You selected ID from the table' || ' ' || p_input || ' ' || 'ID   is' ||' ' || v_department_id);

EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No data found');
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' I petty the fool who wrote this');
END;
```

I seem to be unable to understand how would one get to use the "INTO" clause in this procedure.
I'm reading up on the issue and doing some "tests" although I believe it to be great help
if someone could explain this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INTO goes behind the execute immediate as in

```
declare
    foo number;
    bar number;

begin
    execute immediate 'select 1,2 from dual' into foo, bar;
    dbms_output.put_line(foo ||','||bar);
end;
/
```

This prints:

```
1,2
```

Note that if you find youeself using dynamic SQL, it is often a good idea to review your design.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I tried it, but most of made some mistake while "trying" it, now it works, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pro_two_tables (i_table_name VARCHAR2)
IS
   v_record_id     NUMBER;
   v_record_name   VARCHAR2 (500) := 'Name Record'; -- Insert your Name Value
   sql_stmt        VARCHAR2 (500);
BEGIN
   sql_stmt :=
      'SELECT id
           FROM ' || i_table_name || ' WHERE name = :1';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt INTO   v_record_id USING v_record_name;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(   'You selected ID from the table'
                        || ' '
                        || i_table_name
                        || ' '
                        || 'ID   is'
                        || ' '
                        || v_record_id);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No data found');
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (' I petty the fool who wrote this');
END;
```

With EXECUTE IMMEDIATE you can USE:

1. INTO for Return Single Value o BULK COLLECT INTO for Multiple Value.
2. USING for replace Bind Variable in your query statement that you place in your sql with format :  [name_field]